# get base64 with PixiJS

Tags: canvas, base64, pixi.js

I add some effects like contrast or brightness thanks to pixi but I want to return back. So, I want to use base64 to generate new sprite on canvas.

The console.log() returns to me a string that not corresponds to my canvas

Here is code :

```
let app             = new PIXI.Application({width: 5376, height: 2688, backgroundColor: 0x000000});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);
let renderer        = app.renderer;

var container       = new PIXI.Container();
container.x = app.screen.width / 2;
container.y = app.screen.height / 2;
app.stage.addChild(container);

let sprite          = new PIXI.Sprite.fromImage('./o8rvhb.jpg');
sprite.width        = 5376;
sprite.height       = 2688;
sprite.anchor.set(0.5);
container.addChild(sprite);

let data =  renderer.plugins.extract.image(container);
console.log( data.src );
```

**UPDATE**

After several tests I show you the result

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    let app             = new PIXI.Application({width: 5376, height: 2688, backgroundColor: 0x000000});
    document.body.appendChild(app.view);
    let renderer        = app.renderer;

    var container       = new PIXI.Container();
    container.x = app.screen.width / 2;
    container.y = app.screen.height / 2;
    app.stage.addChild(container);

    let sprite          = new PIXI.Sprite.fromImage('./o8rvhb.jpg');
    sprite.width        = 5376;
    sprite.height       = 2688;
    sprite.anchor.set(0.5);
    container.addChild(sprite);

    $( "#exportButton" ).on( "click", function() {
        let data =  renderer.plugins.extract.image(container);
    } )
} )
```

I think it's not possible to get data at the start but I don't understand why. Does someone have a response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use `$('canvas')[0].toDataURL` at the end Pixi puts all that in canvas.

Here is an example

```js
function toDataURL() {
    $('#base').val($('canvas')[0].toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0));
}


var app = new PIXI.Application({width: 500, height: 140});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

var url = 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0496/1029/files/Freesample.svg?5153'
var loader = PIXI.loader;
loader.add(url);
loader.load(function () {
    var sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(new PIXI.Texture.fromImage(url))
    app.stage.addChild(sprite)
    sprite.rotation = -0.5;
    toDataURL()
});

$("#exportButton").on("click", toDataURL);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.1/pixi.min.js"></script>
<script> PIXI.utils.skipHello(); </script>

<input id="base" size="60">
<button id="exportButton">Export</button>
<br><br>
```

Here is the same code in an html page:
http://heldersepu.github.io/hs-scripts/HTML/PixiJS.html

Comment: thanks for your reply, but reading the documentation, i don't understand when should i use PIXI.loader. PIXI.loader is used to wait for the end of loading?

Comment: My use of PIXI.loader was just to create a sample canvas, you don't have to do the part that you should focus on is the use of `toDataURL`

Comment: first i try to execute your code in a new file and it's not working. I'm on Mozzila Firefox. When i use click event if i don't put $( document ).ready() function it's not working. After doing some research i find another way. Why it's not working with .toDataURL()

Comment: @wyllisMonteiro Take a look here: http://heldersepu.github.io/hs-scripts/HTML/PixiJS.html that is a "new file" and it works correctly, your file probably did not have the correct order

Comment: @wyllisMonteiro Did you figure out what was wrong with your file?

Comment: nop, i note i should init $(document).ready but i don't know why for the moment

Comment: yes, sure your file works well but why my file put at the top doesn't work?

Comment: @wyllisMonteiro Can you provide a link to the actual file

Comment: it's at the top but i don't know how to create snippet

Comment: @wyllisMonteiro Are you having troubles with a file or a snippet? if you need a snippet you can use the one I gave in my answer as a template and build from that, if you are working on an actual file add it to GitHub and I help you there.

Comment: @wyllisMonteiro, The image you provide  `'./o8rvhb.jpg'` is a local path, that will not translate well to a snippet because that image only exists in your environment